# how to get the sum of values in the different field in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, select, sum

I have a mysql table name `payment` (contains payments made by the customer) and another table called `lead` (contains customers). When the customer makes a payment it will be added in the `payment` table with customer id row by row. I want to fetch the sum of the paid amount of the particular customer using the `customer_id`.

How can I do it with mysql SUM function ?

Comment: I have tried to sum out but it was not coming due to the wrong execution of the query...now i have used erwin's answer below. It worked:) thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
SELECT sum(payment) AS payment_sum
FROM   payment
WHERE  customer_id = <your_id>
```

An explicit GROUP BY is not needed in this case, because mysql assumes the right thing automatically. May be needed in a more complex query.
Start by [reading the manual here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

Answer (score 1):

To select the sum of payments for a single customer:

```
SELECT SUM(p.amount) FROM payment p WHERE p.customer_id = 42
```

To select the sum for payments for each customer:

```
SELECT SUM(p.amount) FROM payment p GROUP BY p.customer_id
```

Comment: Why use `GROUP BY` when there's only one customer_id?

Comment: Good point. I was mixing that with selecting the sum for each member (`SELECT SUM(p.amount) FROM payment p GROUP BY p.customer_id`).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I started out by doing as well, until I reread the question and noticed three other answers in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(paid_amount) from payments where customer_id = x
```